# targeted links do not always appear in iframe,

Tags: html

Ran into a strange behaviour with iFrames and have no idea what's causing it or how to work around it.

I have two links which I target the to an iFrame.
Sometimes when I select a link it appears in the iFrame other times is opens in a new tab.
I have tried this code in chrome, firefox, edge and ie all exhibit the same issue.

To duplicate the issue just click the links a few times.
Any thoughts?

```html
<html>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.hp.com" target="picture_frame">HP </a><br />
    <a href="https://www.ibm.com" target="picture_frame">IBM </a><br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <iframe width=50% height=50% name="picture_frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it simply depends on the link. 'http://www.hp.com' does not seem to be the actual simple address as it redirects based on location and language. If you want a simple kind of hacky fix you can just go to a direct link. I am from Canada so my link is "https://www.hp.com/ca-en/home.html" while the US link is "https://www.hp.com/us-en/home.html"

```html
<html>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.hp.com/au-en/home.html" target="picture_frame">HP </a><br />
    <a href="https://www.ibm.com" target="picture_frame">IBM </a><br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <iframe width=50% height=50% name="picture_frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

See the IBM link will send the user to a language specific one but the hp does not seem to redirect to its home.html page

Comment: I changed the hp link to https://www.hp.com/au-en/home.html which didn't seem to make any changes to the odd behaviour.  by clicking either of the links a few times eventually (after 3 or for clicks) the pages opens in a new tab and not the targeted iframe.

Comment: @MarvinSchwartz thats odd as it works fine for me in these code snippets

Comment: Strange, would you mind using <a href="https://www.hp.com/au-en/home.html" target="picture_frame">HP </a><br /> for the hp link, then clicking the IBM link followed by the HP link and then IBM again. When I do this the second time I use the IBM link it opens in a new tab not the iframe. Thanks.

Comment: @MarvinSchwartz oh interesting, yea I don't know why it does that. I mean really you could just use some Javascript, make both of these links buttons and then just clear and reload the iframe each time.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to know it's not just me. Looks like a bug in the targeting function.

Comment: I have reported this to WHATWG and will code this in javascript. 
Will close this as no fix.